# Reorder and preserve php array based on given keys

Tags: php, arrays

wondering if it's possible to reorder a php array based on given keys, currently I have an array that looks like this:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "to" => "test"
    "name" => "name"
    "type" => "custom"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "to" => "test 2"
    "name" => "name 2"
    "type" => "page"
    "target" => "test"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "to" => "my link"
    "name" => "something"
    "type" => "custom"
    "target" => "_blank"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "to" => "https://github.com/"
    "name" => "github"
    "type" => "custom"
    "target" => "_parent"
  ]
]
```

On the frontend I'm using sortableJs to allow users to reorder the items to their liking, when the `onSort` event is fired I collect all of the ids inside of the `sortable` container and send it to the php function.

the data that sortable send looks like this

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "0"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "1"
  3 => "3"
]
```

Where the value is the order that they're supposed to be in, so based on this data the original array would need to be this

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "to" => "test"
    "name" => "name"
    "type" => "custom"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "to" => "my link"
    "name" => "something"
    "type" => "custom"
    "target" => "_blank"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "to" => "test 2"
    "name" => "name 2"
    "type" => "page"
    "target" => "test"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "to" => "https://github.com/"
    "name" => "github"
    "type" => "custom"
    "target" => "_parent"
  ]
]
```

I've been thinking about this but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I love these! My solution would be

```
$sorted_array = array_map(
    function($index) use ($original_array){
        return $original_array[$index];
    },
    $sort_order
);
```

Where `$original_array` is your original array and `$sort_order` is the data that sortable sends.

EDIT: This only shuffles the values around, it does not conserve the keys. Your array is not an associative array, and your keys are not in fact keys but indices, and will always be displayed in order.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would help

```
$original // your original array
$sortable // your returned array;
$i = 0;
foreach ($sortable as $key=>$value) { // where value is the new key
$newArrayOrder[] = array($value[$i] => $original[$i]);
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explaing how and why it works in solving the problem?